# How do I enable rating on deletion for my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone

I'm building an iPhone application and I'm new to this, but I was wondering: is there something specific I need to do to enable the rating on deletion behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to enable it, it's automatic.

Comment: Except for OS 4.0+, where it has now (thankfully) been removed by Apple.